# Video won't record

Tags: camera, video-recording

Sprint LG Optimus G Android 4.1.2

Default camera app

Video has stopped recording.  When I hit record, all the settings icons disable for about 4 seconds, then it goes back to a Red highlighted button.  I feel like it coincided with Google+ introducing the Photos app.

Still photos work fine.  Plenty of space left on the device.

Comment: Have you tried clearing data from the camera app?

Comment: Have you tried another camera app? There could be something happening with the storage. Maybe you are running out of room, or the sdcard is going bonkers.

Comment: How do I clear data from the camera app?  When recording w/ Instagram, it acts like its recording, but when it completes there's nothing saved.

Comment: huh - Zoom Camera by Moula Soft Inc. says "Oops! Video recording is not working in your cellphone right now!"

Comment: Tried rebooting the device?

Comment: Many times.  I also went to the task manager to kill apps that might have been running using the camera.